# Why am I able to evaluate "</html> $var </html>" in bash under certain conditions, but not others?

Tags: html, bash, io, eval

I'm trying to load an html template from a directory, substitute the a couple variables denoted with $, and then write the result to a new file. This is the code I originally had, which worked fine:

```
echo \
"<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset=\"utf-8\">
      <meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE-edge,chrome=1\">
      <title>$title</title>
      <meta name=\"description\" content=\"\">

      $scripts

      <script>
          //enter code here
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      $body
   </body>
</html>">"$fileName.html"
```

All of the variables were evaluated as I'd expected. When trying to load from a template, however (the template being identical to the argument I gave to the echo command above, minus the `>"$fileName.html"` and quotations, stored in a .html file), I can't get things to evaluate the same way.

This is what I tried first. I thought it would evaluate like my original code, but it left the literal `$title`,`$scripts`, etc:

```
while read line; do
    newDoc=$(echo "$newDoc$line\n")
done < $pathToHTML

echo -e "$newDoc"
```

I then tried using `eval`, but it gave me an error. Apparently the `>` character is special, and it was trying to interpret it:

```
while read line; do
    newDoc=$(echo "$newDoc$(eval $line)\n")
done < $pathToHTML

echo -e "$newDoc"
```

Why did it evaluate correctly in the original code, but not in either of the template versions? Is the original version using a more selective `eval` like command behind the scenes? If so, how can I use it/how do I solve my problem? Thanks.

Comment: A simpler way to get the contents of a file into a variable is `newDoc="$(<$pathToHTML)"`, but that won't solve your issue. Bash doesn't recursively expand variables. When bash sees `"$newDoc"`, it replaces that with whatever the value of `$newDoc` is and tat's it. If, on the other hand, it sees an unquoted `$newDoc`, it replaces it with the value of the variable and then does word-splitting and glob (filename) expansion. But it still doesn't expand `$var` nor does it do quote removal or backslash-substitutions. (`echo -e` will do backslash-substitutions, but it's a separate process.)

Comment: @rici Hmm, bummer. Thanks for the shortened file reading method.

Comment: Why not just use some existing template system, like mustache? According to google, it even exists for bash -- https://github.com/jwerle/mush -- but there are a multitude of implementations.

Comment: @rici I wasn't aware of it; I thought this would be a good exercise regardless, so I didn't look too hard for existing shell based template systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you'd want to do with the eval is

```
newdoc=$newdoc$(eval "echo \"$line\"")
```

because you want the shell to expand variables.  But rather than using the loop, you can just do this:

```
expanded=$(eval "echo \"$(<file)\"")
```

and do the variable expansion for the whole template in one pass.

Comment: Just confirmed; does exactly what I want. Thanks.

Comment: Warning: as usual with `eval`, this can fail if the data (i.e. the template) is not as expected. For example, if it contains a double-quote that isn't properly escaped, you'll get an unexpected EOF error. Also, if it contains something like `$(command)`, `command` will actually be executed.

Comment: Good note, @gordon. This is a pretty dangerous thing to do in general, so a production app would definite need some validation on the template. :)